# Bootstrap's split button group incorrect height

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

There is some problem with browser output while using Bootstrap's split button groups.

Consider the below `HTML`:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg dropup">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">SQL Server</button>
    <button class="btn btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li> 
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**Current Output:**

[image: output]

**Expected Output:**

[image: Want a caret like that]

Comment: Please post all your code, including CSS and JS

Comment: @ChrisHappy given code is complete . Actually m using bootstrap in my MVC application

Comment: Could you also post your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted all your code, I have made a simple JS function that might not be very quick if you have a lot of buttons on your site.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsAfterHeight = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
 var buttonsIntHeight = buttons[i].clientHeight;
  
 if (buttonsIntHeight > buttonsAfterHeight) {
   buttonsAfterHeight = buttonsIntHeight;
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].style.height = buttonsAfterHeight + "px";
};
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg dropup">

<button class="btn btn-primary">SQL Server</button>
<button class="btn btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li> 
</ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're markup works fine. Make sure you're using the latest 3.x version of Bootstrap, and there is not other CSS overriding the button styles.

http://www.codeply.com/go/YHfmz2wl4s